# Else If Statement in c#

Tags: c#

I start off with an 'if' statement then go onto to use 'else if', then another 'else if'. It's when a new class starts. The 1st starts off with an If, then second and third, else if.

What is the difference between if statement, else if statement, and an if else statement? I'm utterly confused. Any clarification would be extremely helpful

```
 **if (selectedClass == 1)**
            {
                if (i >= 5)
                {

                    if (i >= 5 && j >= 10)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("\nI am sorry, there are no more seats on the flight");
                        break;

                    }

                    Console.WriteLine("\nThere are no first class seats available. Would you like an economy class seat? Type y for yes and n to exit.");
                    selectedClass = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());


                    if (selectedClass == 'y' || selectedClass == 'Y')
                    {
                        reserveEconomySeat(ref seats, ref j);
                    }

                    else 
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("\nThe next flight leaves in 3 hours.");
                        break;
                    }
                }

                else reserveFirstSeat(ref seats, ref i); 
            }


            **else if (selectedClass == 2)**
            {
                if (j >= 10)
                {

                    if (i >= 5 && j >= 10)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("\nI am sorry, there are no more seats on the flight");
                        break;

                    }

                    Console.WriteLine("\nThere are no economy seats available. Would you like a first class seat? Type y for yes and n to exit.");
                    selectedClass = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());

                    if (selectedClass == 'y' || selectedClass == 'Y')
                    {
                        reserveFirstSeat(ref seats, ref i);
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("\nThe next flight leaves in 3 hours.");
                        break;
                    }
                }

                else reserveEconomySeat(ref seats, ref j);
            }


            **else if (selectedClass == 0)**
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nNext flight leaves in 3 hours.");
                break;
            }


            else if (selectedClass == 3)
            {
                DisplaySeatingChart(ref seats);
            }


            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nInvalid entry. Please try again");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Isn't it the task of your tutor to teach you that? I mean, (s)he gets paid for doing exactly that, right...? Also, why don't you just take some time, google for something like "C# if" and spend some time reading...?

Comment: Why not run it in the debugger and see.  Change variables.  Notice the effect.  Experiment. Predict.  That's how to learn.  Anything else is just plain lazy

Comment: Well you're definately not going to learn other than _how to pass an exam_

Comment: Yeah, surprising how many people who do not want to do their homework never ever found something using Google. It's like they are always given big state secrets to investigate...

Answer (score 1):

`If` statement simply executes the code after it if the condition is true:

```
if (condition)
{
    //This code gets executed when the condition is true
}
```

`Else` (you called it `If else`) only executes the code after it if the if (else) statement before didn't execute:

```
if(condition)
{
    //Gets executed if condition is true
}
else
{
    //Gets executed if condition is false
}
```

`Else if` executes the code if the if (else) statement before didn't execute *and* the condition is true:

```
if(condition1)
{
    //Gets executed if condition1 is true
}
else if(condition2)
{
    //Gets executed if condition1 is false and condition2 is true
}
```

For more information read through [this](https://www.dotnetperls.com/if).

Answer (score 1):

Looks are you quite new to C#.
1.

```
 if(condition)
 {
 //block
 }
```

In this scenario the block will get executed if the condition becomes true.

2. ```
   if(condition)
   {
    //block1
   }
   else
   {
    //block2
   }
   ```

if condition become true, block1 will get executed else block2

3. Third case will be if else ladder.

You may start watching video series available on Youtube, Pluralsight. And dont just jump on C# directly. Start with C language, where you are develop your logic building skills

Comment: I shouldn't be as new to c# as I am. Not very big with coding, but this helps a bunch. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Just as the other's mentioned,

The code within the curly braces "{ }" underneath an "if" will be executed when "if (x)" condition is true.

The "else" simply encases what will be executed if the condition is false or not met.

An "else if" can be used if you wanted more than two possible conditions.

For example,

```
if(x > 5 && <= 10){
//execute
}else if (x > 11 && <= 20){
//execute
}else{
//execute
```

}

Hope this helps